# How to get the current line length in VI editor?

Tags: vi, aix

Is there a way to check the length of the current line where the cursor is currently in the VI editor? I tried searching in Google but all I could find is how to see the line number in the currently opened file using "set nu".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write to current line to a shell command:

```
:.w !wc -c
```

Also note that the length with `wc -c` includes the `\n`. When you don't want that, substract one or use something like

```
:.w !tr -d '\n'|wc -c
```

Comment: What does `.w` do?

Comment: The dot is the current line. Without the w that stands for write the current line would be replaced by the output of the system call.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$` to move the cursor to the end of the line, then `<ctrl>g` to display row and column information (along with filename and edit status), looking something like this:

`"big.csv" [Modified] line 400 of 866 --46%-- col 504`

Going one step further, if using `vim`, you can enable row and column info to always be displayed in the lower right corner by turning on the ruler with `:se ruler`.  Then you'll see something like the following get updated whenever the cursor moves:

`400,504       46%`

You can add `:se ruler` to your `.vimrc` to make this setting the default whenever `vim` is launched.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of the current line with `strwidth` and `getline`. From `:h getline`

```
                            *getline()*
getline({lnum} [, {end}])
        Without {end} the result is a String, which is line {lnum}
        from the current buffer.  Example: >
            getline(1)
<       When {lnum} is a String that doesn't start with a
        digit, line() is called to translate the String into a Number.
        To get the line under the cursor: >
            getline(".")
<       When {lnum} is smaller than 1 or bigger than the number of
        lines in the buffer, an empty string is returned.
```

and from `:h strwidth`:

```
strwidth({expr})                    *strwidth()*
        The result is a Number, which is the number of display cells
        String {expr} occupies.  A Tab character is counted as one
        cell, alternatively use |strdisplaywidth()|.
        When {expr} contains characters with East Asian Width Class
        Ambiguous, this function's return value depends on 'ambiwidth'.
        Also see |strlen()|, |strdisplaywidth()| and |strchars()|.
```

Putting this all together, you could do

```
echo strwidth(getline('.'))
```

to echo the length of the current line. Of course, you could also get the length of a specific line by changing the argument.

```
echo strwidth(getline(3))   "Length of line 3
echo strwidth(getline('$')) "Length of the last line
```

Comment: Hi, should I use it after opening the file in VI and pressing `:` key?

Comment: @Mistu4u Yes, this is an `ex` command, so you will need a colon.